# Ajax, jquery request from api site

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, jsfiddle

I just want to make a simple request with jquery but it freaking won't work. 
I don't know why. Can you say me what i did wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/k6uJn/

There is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.asdasdasdsdsad.com",
    timeout: 5000,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
            $('.galleryThreeColumnList photoSwipe').append('<li><a href="' + item.photo + '"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" alt="' + item.id + '" /></a></li>')
        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

});

Greez Edocsyl

Comment: Check your error console. It's a CORS issue. You can't do AJAX calls between domains so easily. *Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*

Answer (score 2):

That is because the site you are trying to access is on a different domain than yours.

Javascript has a [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) where you cannot make ajax request from a website on a different domain.

Comment: But i tryed it local with the Mozilla Firefox and it wont work too.

Comment: your local `http://localhost/` and the api `http://api.elublu.com` are 2 different domains

Answer (score 1):

Using AJAX for requesting remote pages is generally not possible. As the chrome developer console suggests,

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.elublu.com/. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Requesting remote pages would be theoretically possible with [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but if CORS had been enabled in this api, you would see

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

in the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
```

Should this actually be as follows? You are using variable called json further down which is not declared...

```
success: function(json) {
```

Comment: Yes sadly the other answers are also valid!

Answer (score 0):

Like a lot of them have already mentioned it is a cross-domain call which could be causing that issue.

You can use [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) which doesn't have same origin policy restrictions (not sure if this meets your requirements though)

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.asdasdasdsdsad.com",
        timeout: 5000,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
                $('.galleryThreeColumnList photoSwipe').append('<li><a href="' + item.photo + '"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" alt="' + item.id + '" /></a></li>')
            });
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```